# If statement doesn't work in a function

Tags: php, html, mysql, if-statement, pdo

Not sure if this is a common problem or not, but I ran upon it.  When trying to put a if/else statement into a function, it simple does not work.  But when do the if/else without the function, it does work (So, I know that the if/else is correct).

I have 2 separate documents, `Home.php` and `Functions.php` here is what I have inside those files"

`Home.php` (the PHP)

```
<?php
$db = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=TEST;charset=utf8","Xero",""); 
include("Functions.php");

menu();
?>
```

And then we have the `Functions.php` (the PHP)

```
<?php 
$db = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=TEST;charset=utf8","Xero",""); 

function menu() {
    echo "
    <div id='menu'>
        <div id='user-menu'>
    ";
        // Check AutoLogin-User then :
        $getAutoUser = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM `users-PHP_FNC` WHERE `ip`='" . $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'] . "'");
        $getAutoUser->execute();
        if ($autoUser = $getAutoUser->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
            echo "
            " . $autoUser['user'] . "
            ";
        } 
        // If no AutoLogin-User was found:
        else {
            echo "
            Test
            ";
        }
    echo "
        </div>
    </div>
    ";
}
?>
```

Not sure why this doesn't work.  Are you not allowed to have if/else statements in a PHP function?

Comment: I don't see a function

Comment: Oh, whoops, let me update that.

Comment: Maybe something to do with `=` instead of `==`? Or is that just a typo? `$autoUser = $getAutoUser` Maybe don't assume some complicated problem with the language, just take a good look at what you wrote.

Comment: Yeah, my grammar fails.

Comment: Two things to note: 1) You don't need to reconnect to the database in `functions.php`. If you're including functions.php into a php file which has already established the connection, you can reuse that connection. 2) the `$db` variable wont be in the scope of your `menu()` function. You would need to either include the `$db` variable in the scope of the function, by using `global $db` within your function, or pass `$db` as an argument to `menu()`, like `menu($db)`.

Comment: @PhilCross  Thank you, I'm aware I connected twice.  And thank you for letting me know about passing in `$db`!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually, you can be sure that `if ... else` statements **work** inside the scope of a function.

Therefore, the problem lies elsewhere... But there is another thing that you should do:

```
// Replace this
if ($autoUser = $getAutoUser->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))

// By this
if ($autoUser == $getAutoUser->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
```

Why ?

Because when you say `if ($something = $somethingElse)` you tell PHP different things in a particular order:

> **1st** => assign the current value of $somethingElse to $something
>
> **2nd** => test if $something and $somethingElse share the same value

2nd becoming obviously true because of 1st.

To bypass the 1st step, simply use `==` in place of `=`.

Comment: Okay, thanks, I'll accept when I can.  Learn something new everyday.

Comment: You should accept @PHPGlue's answer because he's pointed the right thing. I just mentioned something that you will find useful, but which is not directly causing the problem you're facing now.

Comment: but this did fix my problem.  PHPGlue just kinda added on.

Answer (score 1):

`$db` is not in the function's scope. You would have to pass it in. I would make my code more like:

```
// connect.php - should be in a separate secure folder I'll call restricted
<?php
function db(){
  return new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=TEST;charset=utf8', 'Xero', '');
}
?>

// index.php
<?php
include_once 'restricted/connect.php';
function menu(){
  $db = db();
  echo "<div id='menu'><div id='user-menu'>";
  // Check AutoLogin-User then :
  $getAutoUser = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM `users-PHP_FNC` WHERE ip='{$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']}'");
  $getAutoUser->execute();
  if($autoUser = $getAutoUser->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
    echo $autoUser['user'];
  } 
  else{
    // If no AutoLogin-User was found:
    echo 'Test';
  }
  echo '</div></div>';
}
```

Comment: You're right, but it doesn't really answer my problem, although that's my fault for not explaining well enough.  But, thank you.